# Как в ImageMagick сменить настройки по умолчанию?

Tags: imagemagick

Есть ли в ImageMagick возможность сменить глобальные настройки? Например, мне необходимо чтобы всем конвертируемым изображениям colorspace устанавливался в RGB.